# 301 Redirect with a variable parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have entries in my .htaccess file that perform 301 redirects like this:

```
Redirect 301 /kansascity-ks-1-day-27sep2015 /index.php?option=com_vikevents&task=viewevent&Itemid=298&itid=266
```

However, I have need to add a variable parameter to the end of the "friendly" url and have it persist in the redirect such that if the following is sent in:

`/kansascity-ks-1-day-27sep2015?source=1`

That is will persist through the redirect like this:

`/index.php?option=com_vikevents&task=viewevent&Itemid=298&itid=266&source=1`

I am not sure how to accomplish this. The .htaccess entries are written by my code on the fly after a triggering event.  the "1" portion will be different at any time and set after the .htaccess entry is made.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to `mod_rewrite` rules to handle this situation:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^kansascity-ks-1-day-27sep2015/? /index.php?option=com_vikevents&task=viewevent&Itemid=298&itid=266 [L,QSA,NC,R=302]
```

Make sure to keep this rule before other rules and test it after clearing your browser cache.

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but it's not working.  This site uses an SSL, I suspect that is having an effect on this working.  Also there are some other rewrite rules.  I've posted what they are:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^nashua-nh-3-day-22apr2016/$ /index.php?option=com_vikevents&task=viewevent&Itemid=298&itid=284 [L,QSA,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.faclevents\.org [nc] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.faclevents.org/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: Maybe it is easier for me to email you directly, if you are open to that please let me know.

Comment: Click on [**edit link**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32762546/edit) below your question and provide this htaccess content there.